# Oop class level syntax

Tags: php

How to create a php class with the tier syntax as in the example?

```
class oop
{
    function variable ( $var )
    {
        return $var;
    }

    function print ( $var )
    {
        echo $var;
    }
}
oop::variable ( $var ) -> print ();
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. The `variable` function doesn't actually do anything, because it just returns its own argument. The `print` method is on class `oop`, so if `$var` is an instance of `oop` (`$var = new oop();`) then `$var->print();` would work, but that's nothing special.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you need, but try this:

```
$var = '1111';
class oop
{
    public $var;
    private function __construct($var){
        $this->var = $var;
    }
    static function variable ( $var )
    {
        return new oop($var);
    }

    function prints ()
    {
        echo $this->var;
    }
}
oop::variable ( $var ) -> prints ();
```

[Demo.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cb80699a94fc647f16ee630397a7f0434765bf7b)

Comment: Another good guess. Not sure the optional argument to `prints` adds anything other than confusion, though.

Comment: Function `print` reserved, so it may throw exception I guess..

Comment: I didn't mean the name, I meant the `$var=''` and `$var ? $var : $this->var` business. The example doesn't require it, and it would lead to messy code, so it might be better to keep it simple and just say `echo $this->var;`

Comment: Fixed. Delete echo $var and delete $var as argument `prints` method. Thank you for advice.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for something like this?

```
class Oop
{
    private $var;

    public function variable($var)
    {
        $this->var = $var;
        return $this;
    }

    function print()
    {
        echo $this->var;
    }
}



$oop = new Oop();
$oop->variable($var)->print();
```

Comment: That's a better guess than I had.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a correct example implementation of the factory pattern.